# Mixin string as argument from command line during compile time

Tags: d

Is there a way to get a string as a command line argument during compile time?

Example:

```
import std.stdio;
void main()
{
    mixin(theString);
}
```

Ideal usage:

`dmd app.d -theString="writeln("foo");`

Comment: why do you need it? i have a few alternative ideas depending on the higher level use case

Comment: I just explored the string mixins abilities of D on the weekend.
The idea was to implement a Brainfuck compiler, which compiles given brainfuck file at compile time into D itself.
This is simple. You just need to get to the string of the brainfuck file, filter for the 8 relevant chars and map or loop over it, producing code for every given char (you can do this with a dict).
I just wanted a possibility to give the target brainfuck file as a command line argument during compilation.
I'll give you a github link, once i am home and reach my laptop.

Comment: ah, well in that case, your solution is prolly about a good as it gets :)

Comment: added repo in answer

Comment: I was just watching Ali Çehreli's C++Now 2017 talk “Competitive Advantage with D" and he mentioned a trick to pass D code as a command line argument to get it compiled and executed immediately, e.g.: `rdmd --eval='writeln("Hello");'` (see page 83 of the [transcript](https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2017/blob/master/05-19-2017_friday/competitive_advantage_with_d__ali_cehreli__cppnow_05-19-2017.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

The only solution i found was using a bash script:

```
echo -n $1 > special_file
dmd source/app.d -J.
```

The program works as follows:

```
import std.stdio;
void main()
{
    mixin(import("special_file"));
}
```

You can see it working at [github](https://github.com/m3m0ry/drainfuck)